# How do you tell if you're running in test mode in the Act framework?

Tags: actframework

How do you determine if you're running in test mode in the Act framework? The `App.instance().mode()` variable only returns `DEV` or `PROD`.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you're running in test mode is indicated by the profile name. So you can do something like:

```
boolean isTest = App.instance().profile().equals("test");
```

Comment: Actually you can alwasy run automate test when app is running in DEV mode (not DEV profile). Just go straight to http://localhost:5460/~/test

Comment: My issue was that I didn't want to start one service when running in test mode, so I needed to know in code whether we were in test mode or not.